# Summary() function in R -not showing statistics

Tags: r

I am trying to get summary statistics for my data set. The dataset is values for different countries cereal yield of a number of years. I want to get the summary statistics and for each year and then transpose the dataset and get the summary statistics for each country.

For some reason I am not getting the summary statistics and just a list of some of the values and the quantity of them.

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

---

Below is a sample of my dataset:

```
row.names   YR1990  YR1991  YR1992
3         1200.6      1160      1097.7
4         320.9       417.4       397
5         2794.3      2071.8    2269.2
6         2216.4      1594      2315.3
7         2232.32     2666.1    3057.3
10        2380.9      1833.3    1722.2
```

---

This is the results I am getting after summary() function:

```
summary(CerialData)
 YR1990        YR1991        YR1992        YR1993        YR1994  
 1000   :  1   1000   :  1   943.2  :  2   1000   :  1   1040.03:  1  
 1003.9 :  1   1043.19:  1   1000   :  1   1055.77:  1   1041.1 :  1  
 1026.7 :  1   1050.3 :  1   1021.2 :  1   1083.3 :  1   1091.6 :  1  
 1028.5 :  1   1055.3 :  1   1042.1 :  1   1109.3 :  1   1100   :  1  
 1033.2 :  1   1094   :  1   1069.7 :  1   1135.5 :  1   1111.1 :  1  
 1036.8 :  1   1108.3 :  1   1072.3 :  1   1153   :  1   1132.2 :  1  
 (Other):158   (Other):158   (Other):157   (Other):158   (Other):158
```

---

```
str(CerialData) 'data.frame':   164 obs. of 20 variables: 
$ YR1990: Factor w/ 188 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 19 116 103 80 81 85 46 153 26 177 ... 
$ YR1991: Factor w/ 191 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 14 141 66 38 93 53 40 154 28 181 ... 
$ YR1992: Factor w/ 207 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 10 151 95 96 134 49 67 165 28 197 ... 
$ YR1993: Factor w/ 194 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 8 97 99 178 107 35 62 153 23 182 ... 
$ YR1994: Factor w/ 214 levels "","..","0","1040.03",..: 11 133 107 74 127 53 15 171 17 207 ...
```

Comment: Could you please include the output from `str(CerialData)`?

Comment: all of your variables are factors. rather than fixing it now, I would go back to your code and figure out how they got that way

Comment: @CephBirk str(CerialData)
'data.frame': 164 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ YR1990: Factor w/ 188 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 19 116 103 80 81 85 46 153 26 177 ...
 $ YR1991: Factor w/ 191 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 14 141 66 38 93 53 40 154 28 181 ...
 $ YR1992: Factor w/ 207 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 10 151 95 96 134 49 67 165 28 197 ...
 $ YR1993: Factor w/ 194 levels "","..","0","1000",..: 8 97 99 178 107 35 62 153 23 182 ...
 $ YR1994: Factor w/ 214 levels "","..","0","1040.03",..: 11 133 107 74 127 53 15 171 17 207 ...

Comment: @rawr I have no idea why my variables are factors, have you any suggestions how this may have happened and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: Depends on how you read the data into R. For example, `read.table` and it's variants will guess at the data type based on the file being read in.  You can set the classes of the fields in the new data.frame by specifying the `colClasses` argument.  See `?read.table` for details.  You could also convert these fields to numeric via `CerialData$YR1990 <- as.numeric(as.character(CerialData$YR1990))`, etc..

Comment: @rawr I am reading the data in as read.csv so yes I now tried CerialData$YR1990 <- as.numeric(as.character(CerialData$YR1990)), and I get back Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion                                                                      (I apologise my coding knowledge is very limited)

Comment: use `read.csv(..., na.strings = c("NA", ".."))` you have some uncommon values to point out missing data, so you need to specify that. you are also trying to convert `".."` to numeric which explains the error

Comment: @rawr Thank you for all this help, I have attempted to remove ".." by converting them to NAs and omitting them and then converting the data to numeric.   I used the following code to remove ".."   NAs <- CerialData == ".."
is.na(CerialData)[NAs] <- TRUE
CerialData<-na.omit(CerialData) I think the issue may be fixed now as I was trying to convert the entire dataset at once but if I do each variable separate it works. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I would read the data in again. `na.omit` will remove all rows which have any NAs which is probably not what you want